# Ember Data 1.0.0 belongsTo Relationship in JSON

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using the RESTAdaptor and Ember-Data 1.0.0-beta-2.  I'm following the guidance in the Ember docs http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/ about how the JSON returned from the server should be formatted for belongsTo relationships - but the related object is not being loaded.  The Ember Inspector in Chrome is always showing the relationship as null.

The format of my JSON from the server is as follows:

```
{
"danceStyle": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Balboa",
    "partnered": true,
    "_links": {
        "parent": "/danceStyles/1"
    }
  }
}
```

And my Model definition is:

```
var attr = DS.attr;
var belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;
var hasMany = DS.hasMany;

App.DanceStyle = DS.Model.extend({
object: attr('string'),
name: attr('string'),
partnered: attr('boolean'),
parent: belongsTo('danceStyle', { inverse: 'children', async: true }),
children: hasMany('danceStyle', { inverse: 'parent', async: true })
});
```

The format of my JSON matches up to the format that the Ember docs say I should be using, so I'm banging my head against the wall trying to work out what's wrong! I've tried other ways of including the relationship within the JSON but with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that `_links` is used for relationships.  (If so it is not well documented at all...)

Since you're using `async:true` you should be able to use JSON like this :

```
{
  "danceStyle": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Balboa",
    "partnered": true,
    "parent" : 1,
    "children" : [3,4]
  }
}
```

At that point, if you had loaded that model and then called `.children()` Ember Data would send a request like `/danceStyles?ids[]=3,ids[]=4`.  Then your server should return :

```
{
  "danceStyles" : [
    {"id":3,...},
    {"id":4,...}
  ]
}
```

Alternatively, you can use "side loading" to deliver the children and parent along with the main model.

```
{
  "danceStyle": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Balboa",
    "partnered": true,
    "parent" : 1,
    "children" : [3,4]
  },
  "danceStyles" : [
    {"id":1,...},
    {"id":3,...},
    {"id":4,...}
  ]
}
```

I haven't actually dealt with side loading for self referential tree type models, but I know it works for an arrangement like `Blog` -> `Post` -> `Comment`.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  I've discovered that it was actually a bug in Ember Data, where the belongsTo relationship wasn't returning a PromiseObject.  They've just fixed it today in this commit https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/3d51dcf6576760a3040183b1aae6b56d126178df  I've now got it working and you're right that I don't have to use the _links relationship - seems some of their docs are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following:

```
{
  "danceStyle": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Balboa",
    "partnered": true,
    "parent": 1
    "children": []  
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, tried that at the time and it wasn't working.  Have discovered that you're right that's what the format should be but there was a bug in Ember Data which they've just fixed in a recent commit.  So it's now working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you cannot use the "links" attribute for a belongsTo relationship. This can only be done with a hasMany relationship.

EDIT 9/23/14

"links" now works for both hasMany and belongsTo relationships. "links" away!